# Torah learning any time of the day

Tags: halacha, torah-study, evening-night, birchos-hatorah

Can I wake up at any time of night/early morning, say birchat haTorah, and begin to learn?

Is there any time of night/early morning I cannot do this?

Is there ever a time in which learning Torah is not allowed?

For example, if it's about 25 minutes to alot hashachar, do I wait for alot hashachar to say all the morning brachot, including birchat haTorah, and then learn Torah, or can I say birchat haTorah even 25 minutes before alot hashachar and learn Torah, and then at alot hashachar or a bit after that time, say the birchat hashachar?

Comment: Yes learning Torah is Mutar/Chayav all day (Menahot 99, Harav Musafi Shelit"a).

Comment: So I get up, wash my hands, say the birchat hoTorah and learn, no matter what time of night/early morning it is?

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/whats-the-best-way-to-disentangle-these-questions-about-rising-early-washing

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Mishnah Brurah says yes (he says that you don't need to be concerned for the opinion of the Maharshal (?) who says no)

Answer (score 1):

There are minogim not to learn Tora shebektav between shkiya and hazot and not to learn at all in nitl - between shkiya and hazot at Christmas